# How to use the latest CMAKE 3.11 built in home directory instead of inbuilt CMAKE 2.8 in root directory?

Tags: cmake

There is cmake 2.8.12.2 installed in usr/bin/cmake directory. I installed CMAKE 3.11 in my home directory (Since I don't have elevated privileges). 
My question is how to call the CMAKE 3.11 version for my projects instead of the cmake 2.8.12.2 which is already installed in root folder.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Simply run cmake using its absolute path: `/home/<user>/<path-to-cmake-3-11> ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!!! I thought whether if some variables needs to added in $PATH or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH